# How to use a class in an interface's default implementation

Tags: c++, qt, class, interface, polymorphism

I have written a class `MyClass` that I would like to use in an interface's default implementation.

```
class MyDefaultInterface
{
public :
    virtual ~MyDefaultInterface() {}

    virtual QWidget *myDefaultQWidget()
    {
        // Do something with an object of `MyClass` here
        return NULL;
    }
};

#define MyDefaultInterface_iid "com.myproject.MyDefaultInterface"

Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(MyDefaultInterface, MyDefaultInterface_iid)
```

How can I go about it?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: you can add reference of myClass as member variable in interface

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. You could use C++ `dynamic_cast` or take advantage of Qt [meta object protocol](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/metaobjects.html) e.g. thru [QMetaObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html)